# Apostrophe input field validation

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I want to add a validation to an Apostrohe input field. Suppose I have an input field of type string and i want apostrophe to throw an error if the user had entered some specific text(say hi)

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

In Apostrophe you can create your own field types, which is useful for these kind of project-specific requirements. These custom field types can have their own validation and sanitization methods and requirements.

The documentation outlines what is needed to write your own field here https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/intermediate/custom-schema-field-types

Since you're not creating a new UI (you're borrowing from the existing `string` field type) I would use the `string` field type as a guide in the source.
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/index.js#L1089

Use the errors it throws for `min` and `max` as your guide for throwing errors.

If you have specific issues down the road please follow up!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Stuart, As u mentioned i just need to extend the existing string from the schema and add a validation. In the example provided above(second one) are we completely writing a new schema?. Im asking this because i could see every object rewritten inside the guide. Or is there any way just to override the string,modify self.error and accomodate the change.